# In MVVM Light need to do logic for Pressing a button to generate a Database

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, mvvm-light

I'm fairly new to MVVM Light for WPF.  I'm using VIsual Studio 2013 and have created a project using C#.  I've got the logic for a button in xaml.  When the user clicks this button I would like for the app to generate a database and a datatable.  I've got the binding command in the xaml which will fire of the relay command.  I've also got a method in the model to generate the database and datatable.  I've created a relay command in the view model but outside of that I'm not quite sure what to do next.  Any help would be appreciated.

View - xaml

```
<Button Content="New Project" Margin="0,0,3,0" Command="{Binding AddProjectCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding CommNotStreaming}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

View Model -

```
public class ProjectConfigViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //Binding AddProjectCommand
    public RelayCommand AddProjectCommand { get; set; }


    private string consoleText { get; set; }
    private StringBuilder consoleBuilder = new StringBuilder(360);

    public ProjectConfigViewModel()
    {
        this.AddProjectCommand = new RelayCommand(this.AddProject);

    }

    public void AddProject()
    {
          //Not really sure what to do here to call the ProjectDbInteraction class

    }

}
```

Model - Database Interaction class

```
public class ProjectDbInteraction
{
    //String rawDBConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=12_rse_002_db; uid=root; pwd=password; Connection Timeout=5;"; //TODO Either pick a standard for make this edittable

    public void CreateProjectDb(string projName)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("DataSource=localhost;UserId=root;pwd=password");
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE " + projName + ";", connection);
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS " + projName;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Projects(ProjectID INT NOT NULL, ProjectName VARCHAR(VARCHAR(255), ProjectStartDate DateTime, ProjectEndDate DateTime, ProjectNotes VARCHAR(MAX) PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID))";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Metabolites(MetaboliteID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, Metabolite_Name VARCHAR(45) NULL, ReactionTime INT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (MetaboliteID)";
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by replacing

```
this.AddProjectCommand = new RelayCommand(this.AddProject);
```

with

```
this.AddProjectCommand=new RelayCommand(() => AddProject());
```

.

Then in your AddProject() method , that calls your database creation, something like:

```
ProjectDbInteraction.CreateProjectDb("some name");
```